# Setting Libxml2 on VS2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, libxml2

I've installed libXml2 through the nuGet VS utility. After a pletora of LNK2019 resolved, my C++ console app compiled but couldnt run because "**code execution cannot proceed because libxml2.dll wasnt found blah blah blah**". I resolved that copying the dll in the folder where the app exe is, but now i get the same kind of error for, in order, **libiconv.dll** (already downloaded), **MSVCR110.dll** and **zlib.dll** . Do i seriously need to find all these dlls and put them in the app folder or am i missing something? Can someone guide me step by step on configuring libXml2 for VS2019?

Comment: `MSVCR110.dll` means you have the wrong binaries for Visual Studio 2019. That is for Visual Studio 2012. Visual Studio 2019 is compatible with binaries from Visual Studio 2015 and Visual Studio 2017 and no other versions.

Comment: Are you telling me NuGet just picked the wrong version of libxml2?

Comment: Which nuget package did you download?  This one looks more supported for VS2019... : https://www.nuget.org/packages/libxml2-vc140-static-32_64/

Comment: ***I compiled and ran some apps with VS2019 just fine*** They will have Undefined Behavior. [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/binary-compat-2015-2017?view=vs-2019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/binary-compat-2015-2017?view=vs-2019)

Comment: @selbie, i downloaded it now, it gives me a lot of LNK2001 and LNK2019 errors with the __imp__ prefix (does it expect to be linked to a dll rather than a static lib?). How do i solve this?

Comment: Consider just building libxml2 yourself. That's what I would do.

Comment: ***does it expect to be linked to a dll rather than a static lib?*** No you should link to the import lib which should have a `.lib` prefix but it is not a static lib because it does not contain the implementations.

Comment: I use it with the binaries compiled from source using `vcpkg` [https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/tree/master/ports/libxml2](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/tree/master/ports/libxml2)

Comment: Thank you both for your answers! Tomorrow ill try using vcpkg and if i cant make it work ill consider building it by hand. Thank you very much again!